# Vertically centering menu items between menu separator images

Tags: css

This is what I'm trying to achieve, and have come pretty close:

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 55px;
    background: url(../../images/separator.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
    height: 87px;
}       

a {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 67px;
}
```

I'm almost there, but there are a few problems. The only way I came up with to have the menu items vertically in the middle of the separators was to use line-height. But now of course when hovering over the links the hover is the height of the line-height, and I don't want that.

Also: is there a way to have the menu items go "inside" the separator images, like in the picture? The separator image is a transparent png. If not I'll just decrease the padding on the menu items to try and get them closer.

Comment: can you post some markup code?

Answer (score 1):

First method:

Give the link a height, position it 50% from the top, half the height back to top:

```
a {
    font-size: 15px;
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Demo
http://jsbin.com/ovaqix/1/edit

Second Solution

Make the a element display:table-cell and same height as li, then use vertical-align:

```
a  {
  display:table-cell;
  height:87px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Demo

http://jsbin.com/ovaqix/2/edit

Table-cell doesnt work in IE7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing stating a height in a:hover ?

To have the menu items go inside the separators, I think that you need to create after and before pseudo elements, with the border hack to generate triangular shapes. Something in he line of:

```
a:before {
    border-top: 38px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid black;
}
```

If you provide more details, I can be more specific.